# distributivity of min and max over + and · without the assumption of inverses

Tags: lattice-orders, formal-proofs, constructive-mathematics

$\;$Dear SE$.$Mathematics community,

I am trying to prove some properties on a Lattice with a proof assistant and extend these properties by interaction with addition $+$ and multiplication $·$ e.g. on a lattice that is also a ring⁽¹⁾.

In particular I am wondering whether it is possible to proof

$$∀\,x\,y\,∀\,z≥0\,.\,\min(x · z, y · z)=\min(x,y) · z$$

or equivalently

$$∀\,x\,y\,∀\,z≥0\,∀\,w\,.\,w ≤ \min(x · z, y · z)⇒w≤\min(x,y) · z$$

without assuming the existence of multiplicative inverses. This would make the proof hold on a lattice-ring and not only on a lattice-field.

E.g. with the assumption of multiplicative inverses, a proof goes like this:

> $\begin{align}
> &w ≤ \min(x · z, y · z)\\
> &\quad ⇒\text{by is-min}\\
> &w ≤ x · z \quad\text{ and }\quad w ≤ y · z\\
> &\quad ⇒\text{by · preserving ≤ for 0 < z}\\
> &w · z⁻¹ ≤ x · z · z⁻¹ \quad\text{ and }\quad w · z⁻¹ ≤ y · z · z⁻¹\\
> &\quad ⇒\text{by inverse of ·}\\
> &w · z⁻¹ ≤ x \quad\text{ and }\quad w · z⁻¹ ≤ y\\
> &\quad ⇒\text{by is-min}\\
> &w · z⁻¹ ≤ \min(x,y)\\
> &\quad ⇒\text{by · preserving ≤ for 0 < z}\\
> &w · z⁻¹ · z ≤ \min(x,y) · z\\
> &\quad ⇒\text{by inverse of ·}\\
> &w ≤ \min(x,y) · z
> \end{align}$

but I could not come up with a proof without $z⁻¹$. Is that property even derivable then?

regards,
Christian

#### Context

The lattice definition that I am using is:

> Let $(A, ≤)$ be a partial order (reflexive, transitive, antisymmetric), and let $\min, \max : A → A → A$ be binary operators on $A$. Then $(A, ≤, \min, \max)$ is a lattice if $\min$ and $\max$ compute bounds in the sense that for every $x, y, w : A$, we have
>
> **is-min**: $\quad w ≤ \min(x, y)\quad$ iff $\quad w ≤ x$ and $w ≤ y$,
>
> **is-max**: $\quad \max(x, y) ≤ w\quad$ iff $\quad x ≤ w$ and $y ≤ w$.

and I was able to obtain the "usual" lattice-properties from this definition:

> **min-≤** : $∀\,x\,y \,.\, \min(x,y) ≤ x$ and $\min(x,y) ≤ y$
>
> **min-identity** : $∀\,x \,.\, \min(x,x) = x$
>
> **min-comm** : $∀\,x\,y \,.\, \min(x,y) = \min(y,x)$
>
> **min-assoc** : $∀\,x\,y\,z \,.\, \min(\min(x,y),z) = \min(x,\min(y,z))$
>
> ... similar properties for **max**
>
> **min-max-absorptive** : $∀\,x\,y \,.\, \min(x,\max(x,y)) = x$
>
> **max-min-absorptive** : $∀\,x\,y \,.\, \max(x,\min(x,y)) = x$

From antisymmetry and reflexivity of ≤ we get that "≤ reflects equality" in the following sense: for all $x, y : A$

$\quad ∀ z\,.\,z ≤ x ⇔ z ≤ y\quad$ iff $\quad x = y$,

$\quad ∀ z\,.\,x ≤ z ⇔ y ≤ z\quad$ iff $\quad x = y$

and I used this reflection property in the above proofs.

#### Footnotes

(1) a ring (or semiring) with a tight apartness relation and

$\quad$ addition + is <-extensional : $∀\,x\,y\,z\,w\,.\,x + y < z + w ⇒ (x < z\text{ or } y < w)$

$\quad$ multiplication · preserves < : $∀\,x\,y.\,x < y  ⇒ ∀\,z>0\,.\,x · z < y · z$

Comment: I haven't really digested your formalism , so this is a shot in the dark: What if you set things up so that that $x,y $ are $2$ bit binary strings, under lex order, and multiplication by $z$ was shift to the left. For instance, this can be done in the ring $F_2[z]/z^2$ with lexicographic order. Then if $x = (1,0)$, $y = (0,1)$, $ x > y$, but $(0,0) = xz < yz = (1,0)$. So you get $max(x,y)z = xz = (0,0)$ and $max(xz, yz) = yz = (1,0)$. Maybe a counter example like that can work?

Comment: Hi Lorenzo, in order to exclude your counter example this would make a preservation property on <, like $∀\,x\,y\,.\,x<y⇒(∀\,z>0\,.\,x⋅z<y⋅z)$, a necessity then, I guess?

Comment: I think so. I think your desired claim follows from that  property as well -- if $x < y$, then $\min(x,y) z = xz$ and if $xz < yz$ then $\min(xz, yz) = xz$.

Comment: Yes, that should work when trichotomy is available $∀\,x\,y\,⇒\,(x<y)\;∨\;(x=y)\;∨\;(x>y)$.

EDIT:
I was able to proof $∀\,x\,y\,.\,x ≤ y⇒\min(x,y)=x$ but to start with "if $x < y$" would make some kind of case-splitting necessary. Does this work without trichotomy (which we do not have on the constructive reals for example)?

Comment: Well... but we have multiplicative inverses on the constructive reals, so it holds either way. That should suffice for my intended purposes at least where either trichotomy or inverses are available. I'd be just curious whether it is possible to proof this without trichotomy then.